# Case Sensitive Ordering within the CMS Server List

Tags: sql-server, case-sensitive, central-management-server

I've got to believe there's a reason for this, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.  It looks like ordering of Server Names within any Central Management Server is Case SENSITIVE, regardless the collation of the server acting as the CMS, itself.

Attached is an example of a CMS hosted on my local machine, which is configured with a server collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  CI meaning Case Insensitive.  When selecting from the system table holding the CMS objects, the proper order is returned, however as you can see in this screenshot, the way the servers are listed in the UI, the order is obviously being treated in a Case Sensitive manner.

[image]

Since it doesn't seem to be server-level related, I assume it's client tools related, but there is no where within the tools that I can identify a collation level (or even case sensitivity setting) that would affect this.

Obviously there is nothing critical about this question, but if someone does know how to force the UI to be case insensitive, I'd appreciate it as I like to Camel Case my server names which is throwing off the ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a bug and I could reproduce it.
I entered a connect item for it: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3136521